# Larvel 8 POST not supported for this route error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. Laravel 8 error used, what I am doing wrong here?

My form file name -- **insertemp.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="/showemployee">
   @csrf
   <div class="form-group" style="margin-left: 30px">
      <label for="id">ID</label>
      <input class="form-control"  type="number" name="eid" id="empid"><br>
   </div>
</form>
```

My **web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/showemployee',[EmployeeController::class,'show']);
Route::post('/showemployee',[EmployeeController::class,'store']);
```

My controller file -- **EmployeeController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Employee;

class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
   public function show()
   {
      $emp = Employee::all();

      return view('showemployee',['employees' => $emp]);
   }

   public function store()
   {
       echo "I am in store";
       error_log(request('eid'));

       return redirect('/');
   }
}
```

Comment: why don't use the  resource controller?

Comment: @dılosürücü I am new to laravel, I am following a tutorial he used basic controller

Comment: okay look at my answer ,ı shared code example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::post('/showemployee', [EmployeeController::class,'store'])->name('form.post');
```

and

```
<form method="POST" action="{route('form.post')}}" >
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group" style="margin-left:30px">
       <label for="id">ID</label>
       <input class="form-control" type="number" name="eid" id="empid">
    </div>
</form>
```

if still not works

check with :

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: Thanx buddy it worked, my routes where also not updating, that also caused some issues I tried this method earlier now used and ran command php artisan route:cache.

Comment: yes I will can you insert one more curly braces as it is missing in form action field. As if someone refers they should not come up with one more hurdle

Comment: Can you please explain why normal path doesnot work in case of POST

Comment: laravel global route helper generates URI path ... in fact, you can give manually but not recommended, may change port or domain or folder, etc due to you have to use global route helper ...

Comment: Ok mainly due to security reason we can say and also it may be easy i guess only one path in routes need to be changed if in case in future we need to change path of all the same routes.